# Inserting in mySQL a JSON encoded value with special chars fails

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo, json

I am trying to execute this query with PDO:

```
UPDATE categories
SET keywords = '{"bg":["keyword1","\u0431\u044a\u043b\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438 "]}'
WHERE id = 4;
```

The problem is that it seems to record the hex value without the backslashes ("\"). It does show up without the backslashes in my app but also in PHPMyAdmin.

I use exec() on this query, and I have tried it with this full-text query, without any dynamic/transformed variables. The PDO parameters are as follow:

```
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
```

Can someone explain me what is happening here? Thanks!

UPDATE: I have executed this exact query from mysql's CLI, then displayed it there, and the problem is the same: all the backslashes have disappeared. So it doesn't seem the problem has anything to do with PDO, but with MySQL - or me! My version is 5.1.53

Comment: Code samples could help a lot.

Comment: Please add the code relating to your query where you prepare and run it.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem it has anything to do with PHP as I'm getting the same loosy result with mySQL's CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` character has special meaning in SQL. Use [bound parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) instead of hardcoding the value into the base string you use for the query.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I didn't know the backslash had special meaning on its own, without special char after... Shame on me :)